# Where to change formatting of Active Model YAML representation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I am using `YAML::dump` to have a (more or less) simple way to track changes to a database in a git repository. Effectively this means I "dump" parts of the databases to a set of YAML files, commit them and can then track them quite easily. In general this works fine and I am happy with the whole process.

The only problem are embedded `JSON` documents. These store aspects of the data that simply don't work out nicely in a relational model and are sometimes quite complex. `YAML::dump` serializes them as a single-line string (which seems optimal from a storage point of view) but is horrible for diffing. The following example shows the output I currently have:

```
--- !ruby/object:Grammar
concise_attributes:
- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: name
  value_before_type_cast: Dynamisches XML
- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: slug
  value_before_type_cast: dxml
- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: id
  value_before_type_cast: 7e333dff-6d1c-4042-aaa5-0cdf2cfeed7e
- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: model
  value_before_type_cast: '{"root": "element", "types": {"if": {"type": "concrete",
    "attributes": [{"name": "condition", "type": "allowed", "nodeTypes": ["expr"]},
    {"name": "body", "type": "allowed", "nodeTypes": [{"occurs": "*", "nodeType":
    "element"}, {"occurs": "*", "nodeType": "text"}, {"occurs": "*", "nodeType": "interpolate"},
    {"occurs": "*", "nodeType": "if"}]}]}, "expr": {"type": "oneOf", "oneOf": ["exprVar",
    "exprConst", "exprBinary"]}, "text": {"type": "concrete", "attributes": [{"base":
    "string", "name": "value", "type": "property"}]}, "element": {"type": "concrete",
    "attributes": [{"name": "tag-open-begin", "type": "terminal", "symbol": "<"},
    {"base": "string", "name": "name", "type": "property"}, {"name": "attributes",
    "type": "allowed", "nodeTypes": [{"occurs": "*", "nodeType": "attribute"}]}, {"name":
    "tag-open-end", "type": "terminal", "symbol": ">"}, {"name": "elements", "type":
    "allowed", "nodeTypes": [{"occurs": "*", "nodeType": "element"}, {"occurs": "*",
    "nodeType": "text"}, {"occurs": "*", "nodeType": "interpolate"}, {"occurs": "*",
    "nodeType": "if"}]}, {"name": "tag-close", "type": "terminal", "symbol": "<ende/>"}]},
    "exprVar": {"type": "concrete", "attributes": [{"base": "string", "name": "name",
    "type": "property"}]}, "attribute": {"type": "concrete", "attributes": [{"base":
    "string", "name": "name", "type": "property"}, {"name": "equals", "type": "terminal",
    "symbol": "="}, {"name": "quot-begin", "type": "terminal", "symbol": "\""}, {"name":
    "value", "type": "allowed", "nodeTypes": [{"occurs": "*", "nodeType": "text"},
    {"occurs": "*", "nodeType": "interpolate"}]}, {"name": "quot-end", "type": "terminal",
    "symbol": "\""}]}, "exprConst": {"type": "concrete", "attributes": [{"base": "string",
    "name": "name", "type": "property"}]}, "exprBinary": {"type": "concrete", "attributes":
    [{"name": "lhs", "type": "allowed", "nodeTypes": ["expr"]}, {"name": "operator",
    "type": "allowed", "nodeTypes": ["binaryOperator"]}, {"name": "rhs", "type": "allowed",
    "nodeTypes": ["expr"]}]}, "interpolate": {"type": "concrete", "attributes": [{"name":
    "expr", "type": "allowed", "nodeTypes": ["expr"]}]}, "binaryOperator": {"type":
    "concrete", "attributes": [{"base": "string", "name": "operator", "type": "property"}]}}}'
- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: created_at
  value_before_type_cast: '2018-05-15 18:48:12.004676'
- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: updated_at
  value_before_type_cast: '2018-12-20 15:39:19.237639'
- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: programming_language_id
  value_before_type_cast: dxml-eruby
- !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
  name: technical_name
  value_before_type_cast: dxml
new_record: false
active_record_yaml_version: 2
```

A "typical" diff (even though there were only minor changes), then looks something like this:

[image: Unreadable Diff]

So I would prefer to store a nicely formatted string representation of the `model`-attribute instead.

I am suspecting that there is some "Rails magic" going on somewhere behind the scenes. And I do hope there is a API to influence the formatting. But the following things did not work out for me so far:

- Define a matching `*_before_type_cast` method on my model class. This method is not called by `YAML::dump`.
- Define `to_yaml` on my model class. This method is not called either.
- I found out about [`ActiveModel::AttributeSet::YAMLEncoder`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/ActiveModel/AttributeSet/YAMLEncoder) but couldn't figure out how / where this should be used. Or for that matter: How `YAML::dump` ends up using it somehow. It does seem to be responsible for the general format I see.

Comment: How exactly do you dump your models into YAML. Please show your code!

Comment: I am literally using `YAML::dump(myModel, file)`